# $(0)$ is the only minimal prime of $k[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

We define a prime ideal to be minimal if it is minimal with respect to inclusion. Given this, why $(0)$ is the only minimal prime of $k[x,y]$?, where $k$ is any field.

In particular, is there an easy way to see this? If I pick a nonzero prime ideal of $k[x,y]$, how do I know no other prime ideal is contained in it?

Comment: Give me an example of *any* ideal you think is properly contained in $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I pick a nonzero prime ideal of k[x,y], how do I know no other prime ideal is contained in it?

I think you have this backwards. A minimal prime is a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ such that, for all primes $\mathfrak{q}$, if $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, then $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{q}$. Thus, a nonzero prime ideal of $k[x,y]$ which contains no other prime ideal inside it *would* be minimal, and you need to show that there are *no* nonzero minimal primes. In other words, you need to show that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a nonzero prime ideal of $k[x,y]$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ contains a prime ideal (besides itself) – but this is easy because $(0)$ is a prime ideal of $k[x,y]$!

In any case, $(0)$ is contained in every ideal of any ring (in other words, it is the minimal ideal of any ring), so if $(0)$ is a prime ideal of any ring, it must be the unique minimal prime of that ring

Edit: Just to solidify this idea, make sure the following makes sense to you. For any commutative ring $R$, the following are equivalent:

1. $R$ is a domain
2. $(0)$ is a prime ideal of $R$
3. $(0)$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$
4. $(0)$ is the unique minimal prime ideal of $R$

Comment: Thanks. But then wouldn't $(0)$ be the minimal ideal in every ring? And if so, why even make this a definition?

Comment: Minimal ideal, vertainly, but not necessarily minimal prime.